# To live by your values or Living the

Tags: grammaticality

Our (non-English) company recently had a survey where we were asked whether we are "living the (corporate) values". I am very much irked by this phrasing, as I believe it is incorrect usage. It should have been something akin to "living by our values".

Googling the phrase "living the values" did not answer much about the proper usage, as most results were management-speak and blog-posts about "living the corporate values". As a human being, I feel disturbed by such a phrasing.

In short, can the phrase "living the values" be considered proper English?

(PS. The company's corporate values are very reasonable, I do not disagree with them.)

Comment: Well said, KannE, and is exactly why I am irked when corporate wants me to embrace their values...  a lot.

Comment: In the context of corporate-speak, it works.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a peeve. [***Live the American dream***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=live+the+American+dream&year_start=1960&year_end=2010&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true), I say.

Comment: Miles Coverdale had "we ... busyed oure selues to lyue the Gospel" in 1537 so I'd say this one is fairly established. (And easily researchable.)

Comment: It's just business-speak. It has nothing to do with English or communicating any meaning. "Shitting the bullshit".

Comment: @FumbleFingers — In your dreams!